# Replacing Leading Zeros adds carriage return at the end of the string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I replace leading zeros in a string the replace function adds a \r char at the end of the string, the weird part is this works on http://jsfiddle.net but not on Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146.

```
fcode="0000000012'06";
alert("1:"+fcode+" size:"+fcode.length+" lastchar:"+fcode.charCodeAt(fcode.length-1));
var regexp=new RegExp("^0+","g");
fcode=fcode.replace(regexp,'');
alert("2:"+fcode+" size:"+fcode.length+" lastchar:"+fcode.charCodeAt(fcode.length-1));
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: The Regex approach is not working for you?!
I think `fcode.replace(/^0*/g, "")` do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way.

while (fcode.substr(0,1) == '0') fcode = fcode.substr(1);